# Why can't we end a word with "v"?

Tags: spelling

This may sound ridiculous but who can explain the origin of the rule about not ending a word with "**v**"?

To me it still sounds awkward even after so many years of study.

Why cannot we end a word with "**v**"? Why even a closed syllable word should have an "**e**" at the end?

I mean take the word "**love**" and it actually should read "**lowv**" whereas it reads as "**luv**".

Comment: Where did you get this was a rule (as in something prohibited) rather than possibly a rule describing how the language is?

Comment: *Mostly* we can't end a word with **v**.  There's *dev* (although that's short for *developer*) and *shiv*, though.

Comment: It is interesting how many common words have the "silent e," yet that *e* does not change the preceding vowel to its long vowel sound, e.g.: *have* (vs *shave*), *love* (vs *clove*), *shove* (vs *cove*), *give* (vs *gibe*), etc. And then there's _live_, which is pronounce both ways. But I think the question would be better phrased as "Why do we add the "e" to such words?" as opposed to referring to some "rule" that says, "You can't end a word with a _v_,"

Comment: @J.R. good point about the sound changes; I thought of that early on with this question, but OP does have a good point. There aren't really many English words ending with "v" but that seems more an observational rule rather than a prohibitive rule.

Comment: "Love" is one of the ways that it was spelled [in Middle English](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED26245&egs=all&egdisplay=open), back [when e might have been pronounced at the end](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/296222/191178).

Comment: Interestingly, I have heard that the reason that "love" is used to mean "zero" in tennis is because the slang usage back in Henry VIII's time was "l'oeuf," meaning "the egg."

Comment: It has been blamed on the French, but then you'd have to ask why so few French words end in -v. (I suspect that since lots of words end in "f" or "ff", there's also a connection with the fact that /f/ tended to become /v/ between vowels, perhaps in French or Latin even before English, but that doesn't explain why the "e" wasn't dropped when writing these words in modern English.)

Comment: This might be a better question for EL&U. I don't see what it has to do with learning English.

Comment: It's certainly not a strict rule: We have shiv, chav, Slav, etc. If you want to include obvious shortenings you could include improv, rev, perv, listserv, and more. If you want to include names you could include Liv, Kiev, and many others.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan — Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @Jasper Thanks, feel free to submit it as a community wiki if you think it would be helpful. I'm a bit hesitant to submit an answer myself because I agree wtih gotube.

Comment: "In Old English, all the letters in a word were sounded out. There were no silent letters. Many of today’s Silent-e’s were pronounced or aspirated in Old English." The spelling of "love" "have" "give", date back to when it was pronounced.

Comment: There’s “chav”. Bev. Luv. WebDAV. Perv.